# Exchange expectation and gradient in likelihood function with matrix functions

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-processes, matrix, gradient-descent, likelihood

Let us consider $L$ to be a random matrix, i.e. a matrix of random variables $x$, each of them with the probability mass function $f(x;\theta)$ where $\theta$ are the parameters of the pmf.

For example we can imagine $x \sim f(\theta) $ to be the result of a coin toss, where $\theta$ is the probability of head (Bernoulli distribution).

I need to compute the gradients with respect to the parameters $\theta$ of the following quantity:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\mathbb{E}_{\theta} \biggl \lbrack\log \left( \textrm{Tr}\lbrack e^{-\beta L}  \rbrack \right) \biggr \rbrack
$$

where the exponential is the matrix exponential function, $\beta$ is a real positive constant and $\mathrm{Tr}$ is the trace operator, i.e. the sum over the diagonal elements of a matrix.

Following this reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.05254.pdf, I see there are two possible solutions to this problem. The first is to use the score-function estimator.

I could consider $\mathrm{Tr}\lbrack e^{-\beta L} \rbrack$ to be a new random variable (with some complicated distribution $g(\cdot;\theta)$).
This means I have to compute the derivative with respect to $\theta$ of the expectation of its logarithm, resulting in the following:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\mathbb{E}_{\theta} \biggl \lbrack\log \left( \textrm{Tr}\lbrack e^{-\beta L}  \rbrack \right) \biggr \rbrack = \mathbb{E}_{\theta}\biggl \lbrack \log \left( \textrm{Tr}\lbrack e^{-\beta L}  \rbrack \right) \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\log\left( g(x;\theta) \right)\biggr \rbrack
$$

While this could be correct in principle, I am scared that the matrix exponential of a matrix of random variables makes all the things more complicated, as the distribution $g$ is a complicated convolution of distribution and is hard to compute.
I believe this case is not as simple as the simple scalar case, but maybe a solution for $\beta \to 0$ may be simpler.

Is my approach correct or am I missing something?

Comment: The way you have written your first sentence, it appears that the entries of $L$ are independent.  Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, the matrix L is the graph Laplacian of an adjacency matrix (L=D-A). So on the diagonal there is the sum of iid variables and off diagonal they are iid. For example if the elements of the adjacency matrix are Bernoulli distributed, on the diagonal of L they are binomial distributed.